# 18 digits Timestamp in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to create column with 18 digits timestamp in SQL Server?

[image]

My current code is

```
CREATE TABLE TestID
  (
     PnpGuid      UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),
     PnPTimestamp BIGINT NOT NULL
  )

INSERT INTO TestID
            (PnpGuid,
             PnPTimestamp)
VALUES      (NEWID(),
             ( CONVERT (INT, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ))
```

Comment: Use a `bigint`?

Comment: I've try to using bigint. But still fail

Comment: What fails? Show some code

Comment: use a [datetime2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) ?

Comment: What's in the image by the way? can't see it

Comment: CREATE TABLE TestID  
(  
 PnpGuid uniqueidentifier DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID(),  
 PnPTimestamp BIGINT NOT NULL)

insert into TestID (PnpGuid,PnPTimestamp)  values (NEWID(), (convert (int, current_timestamp)))

Comment: This is unreadable in comments. [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55180014/edit) please

Comment: OK right that isn't going to work. What are those time formats? `636876139998310836` Doesn't look like Unix time?

Comment: Why are you storing date/time information in a `bigint` column? There are datatypes for that, e.g. `datetime2`.

Comment: @MartinSmith : I wanna create unix time with 18 digits. Could you tell me how to setting in SQL Server ?

Comment: @HoneyBadger : I'm new for this case. Could you tell me how to setup the table ?

Comment: So that time format looks like .NET ticks not Unix time anyway. `new DateTime(636876139998310836)` is `08.03.2019 03:53:19`. I presume you have no good reason for wanting to store them that way?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, correct. How to setup that format in sql server ?

Comment: Don't, Store them using `datetime2` unless you have some good reason not to. And if so what is that reason?

Comment: But a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01. If you have a value of `636866595499739441`, then according to [unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) that would be `07/07/20181500978 @ 8:30am`!!!!

Comment: @Larnu - yes it is .NET ticks not Unix timestamp

Comment: Seems the OP is *very* confused here @MartinSmith :)

Comment: yep - as they are not clear about the unit I highly doubt that there is going to be any compelling reason for storing them that way.

Comment: I agree with the others. Use the proper data type for this, use `datetime2`

Comment: Case Closed. Just need for convert Datetime2 to Bigint. Thanks all for your answers.